# Cache returning wrong objectForKey with NSIndexPath as key

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath, nscache

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have this code:

```
if ([self.cellImageCache objectForKey:indexPath]) {
        UIImage *image = [self.cellImageCache objectForKey:indexPath];
        [cell.entryView setImage:image];

        return cell;
    }

Entry *entry = [self.appDelegate.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *image = [JTimelineCellContent imageForEntry:entry];

[cell.entryView setImage:image];

[self.cellImageCache setObject:image forKey:indexPath];
```

When I scroll to the bottom of the tableview, each cell displays fine. Upon scrolling back up, cells display fine too. But when I begin scrolling down after scrolling up, cells begin to appear repeated.

Every NSLog search I do for index paths returns the correct value, even on repeated cells.

Answer (score 1):

NsIndexPath is an array actually and not a string.
So your design is flawed.

You could although produce a unique string from the indexPath, by using something like this:

```
NSString *uniqueKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%@%@",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

So you can have:

```
NSString *uniqueKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%@%@",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
  if ([self.cellImageCache objectForKey:uniqueKey]) {
            UIImage *image = [self.cellImageCache objectForKey:uniqueKey];
            [cell.entryView setImage:image];

            return cell;
        }

    Entry *entry = [self.appDelegate.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = [JTimelineCellContent imageForEntry:entry];

    [cell.entryView setImage:image];

    [self.cellImageCache setObject:image forKey:uniqueKey];
```

Comment: I actually tried exactly that, only with a comma between each as it would cause problems otherwise (cell 1,11 and cell 11,1 for example). It still produced the same result.

Comment: Is the cellForRowAtIndexapath called for every cell? Does it find the image in the cache? Do some logs and let me know.

Comment: I also assume you are correctly initializing your cellImageCache dictionary. Right?

Comment: Ah, the problem was it was caught on a previous bit of code, intended to catch the cell if it'd already been generated, to stop it from doing anything further. Apparently this wasn't working correctly.

Comment: Some logging always helps :-)